# a value of <type> cannot be assigned to an entity of <type> (on LwIP)

Tags: networking, freertos, lwip, stm32f4

I want implement a network project using my STM32F4 development board using freeRTOS. For the start. I use tcp/udp echo server. Here's my code

```
static struct netconn *conn;
static struct netbuf *buf;
static struct ip_addr *addr;
static unsigned short port;

   static void udpecho_thread(void *arg)
{
  err_t err;

  LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);
  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
  if (conn!= NULL) {
    err = netconn_bind(conn, IP_ADDR_ANY, 7);
    if (err == ERR_OK) {
      while (1) {
        buf = netconn_recv(conn,&buf);

        if (buf!= NULL) {
          addr = netbuf_fromaddr(buf);
          port = netbuf_fromport(buf);
          netconn_connect(conn, addr, port);
          buf->addr = NULL;
          netconn_send(conn,buf);
          netbuf_delete(buf);
        }
      }
    } else {
      printf("can not bind netconn");
    }
  } else {
    printf("can create new UDP netconn");
  }
}
```

But I get an error on buf = netconn_recv(conn,&buf), and on buf->addr = NULL. And it shows:

> a value of type "err_t" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct netbuf *"

and on buf->addr :

> a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "ip_addr_t"

How I can solve it ?

Comment: netconn_recv returns err_t and not a buffer pointer. The buffer is "returned" via the &buf parameter.

Comment: I think ip_addr_t is a structure so you cannot assign an integer value to a structure.